# Failover when reading from FTP sites using Camel

Tags: ftp, apache-camel

We need to download multiple files on a hourly basis from a vendors FTP site. The vendor provides two ftp sites for fault tolerance with both sites having identical files. I would like to setup a Camel route to download the files from ftp site A if its available and if not try ftp site B. The following code is incorrect but it may highlight what I am trying to achieve.

```
    from("timer://timer1?fixedRate=true&period=60m")
        .loadBalance()
        .failover(-1, false, true)  
        .to("direct:ftp-symbolguides-1")
        .to("direct:ftp-symbolguides-2")
    .end();

    from("direct:ftp-symbolguides-1")
        .to("ftp://SiteA?localWorkDirectory=c:/temp&passiveMode=true&noop=true&idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:size}&idempotentRepository=#idempotentRepository")
        .to("file:/c:/temp/inbox");

    from("direct:ftp-symbolguides-2")
        .to("ftp://SiteB?password=publicftp&localWorkDirectory=c:/temp&passiveMode=true&noop=true&idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:size}&idempotentRepository=#idempotentRepository")
        .to("file:/c:/temp/inbox");
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

When the connection fails by default ftp consumer produces a WARN message instead of throwing an exception, but by the throwExceptionOnConnectionFailed property you can change to throw exception, and handle exception from the
PollingConsumerPollStrategy[1] rollback() method.

http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/spi/PollingConsumerPollStrategy.html

Comment: Thanks for your guidance on this issue. I am very new to Camel but from what I can gather from your thoughts, I will need to update the Consumer instance that is passed in to the rollback method with the IP address of the secondary FTP site and then return false?